# I want to display a form with the data added already

Tags: joomla-4.x, jform, mvc, model, jtable

```
public function getLaymanLayout($id){
    $form = $this->getForm();
    $form->bind(0);
}
```

I still have a lot to implement and make it correct to the MVC rules.

I want to call a table from the db (Table class from Joomla) and then bind the data from that to the form when you press edit.

I'm struggling to get the values of the Database table placed inside of a form when I edit it on the backend of Joomla4. If I understand I have to use the `JTable->bind()` or `JForm->bind()`.

Comment: I don't quite see a question.  Are you stuck? It looks like you have a plan and have simply told us your plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method $form->setProperty() which does this.